# How do I mark a field in MongoDB database after face has been recognized? (OpenCV Model)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I am making a Web-based attendance system using Facial Recognition.
Facial Recognition model is made using OpenCV.
Web-based interface is made using Meteor.JS (integrated with MongoDB).

So my question is how do I integrate the model with the website in order to mark a field in the MongoDB database once the face has been recognized?

Comment: Please share some codes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would create a `Meteor.method({
  afterRecognition(id){
    //do something here like 
     check(id, String)
     DbCollection.update('id', {$set: {recognized: true}})
  }
})`

Once you get a recognition, call the method: `Meteor.call('afterRecognition', id )`